# Save whole path in SQL?

Tags: database-design

I have two tables:

- address: `..., country, state, city ....`
- locations: `..., name, ancestry:`

```
- 1: USA         | 
- 2: NY          | 1
- 3: Wall Street | 2
- 4: Germany     |
- 5: CA          | 1
- 6: Berlin      | 4
```

Should I store in table address all data like country, state, city whether only one field with city is enough?
Should I look for country based on city?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking whether you should use a single field for the address, or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think you should first and foremost do a beginners course in (SQL) databases. I am sure you would find the solution yourself. To me it looks like you want to define several tables and relations among the tables. Your question does not show much research in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should have separate table for Country, State and City
Something like :

```
Country : CountryId, CountryName
State   : StateId,   StateName,  CountryId
City    : CityId,    CityName,   StateId
```

Then, use `CityId` in you `Location` or `Address` table.

Comment: Only CityId in Address ?

Comment: Yes, That will be enough. Otherwise, it will be redundant whenever you enter address which belongs to same city